# Replace image url of a page just using javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have been trying to find a solution of this simple problem but endup asking here as nothing I tried actually worked.

There is some image link on my site like this =

```
<img src="https://wordpress.creativegigs.net/docly/wp-content/themes/docly/assets/img/home_one/b_man_two.png" class="p_absolute one wow fadeInRight" alt="Man illustration" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInRight;">
```

This came with wordpress theme, but looks like they moved the link so this is going to error page, that directory image doesn't exist.

So I want a js code that can replace this link of image src like this = "/assets/img/home_one/b_man_two.png"

I want a js code that can remove this much = https://wordpress.creativegigs.net/docly/ from the src url where ever it exist.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: If those image urls are stored in a database then use any **Search Replace** plugin and replace those urls with your website url or you can use WP CLI if you're familiar with it. If those urls are hardcodes in the php file of your theme then replace those urls in your files.

Answer (score 0):

```js
## If Using JQuery
$('.p_absolute').attr('src',yourImageURL) ;

## If Normal JS
document.querySelector('.p_absolute').setAttribute('src','yourImageURL');
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="https://wordpress.creativegigs.net/docly/wp-content/themes/docly/assets/img/home_one/b_man_two.png" class="p_absolute one wow fadeInRight" alt="Man illustration" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInRight;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
## If Using JQuery
$('.p_absolute').attr('src',yourImageURL) ;

## If Normal JS
document.querySelector('.p_absolute').setAttribute('src',yourImageURL);
```

Comment: Hello brother, there are many links, and it is not possible to add class from query selector, so I need a solution that will replace only this much = " https://wordpress.creativegigs.net/docly/ " to " " empty. i.e it should be like this = " <img src="/wp-content/themes/docly/assets/img/home_one/b_man_two.png " 

So simply we replace https://wordpress.creativegigs.net/docly/ this to empty for all the src places that appears on the  page.